# Normalizer of an abelian subgroup

Tags: representation-theory, lie-groups, weyl-group

Let $ G $ be a connected compact Lie group of rank $ r $ . Let $ T $ be an $ m $ dimensional (proper) closed connected subgroup of $ G $. Let $ N(T) $ be the normalizer in $ G $ of $ T $
$$
N(T):=\{g \in G: gTg^{-1}=T \}
$$
Consider the quotient group
$$ 
N(T)/T
$$
If $ T $ is abelian can we conclude anything interesting about $ N(T)/T $? By "interesting" I mean things like:

(1) Is $ N(T)/T $ always nontrivial? (in other words N(T) contains elements not in $ T $ )

(2) Is $ N(T)/T $ always disconnected?

(3) What is the dimension of $ N(T)/T $?

Here are my thoughts so far:

Let $ W $ be the Weyl group of $ G $. My guess is that (roughly)
$$
N(T)/T \cong   Z(T)/T \rtimes N(T)/Z(T) \cong Z(T)/T \rtimes W 
$$
where $ Z(T) $ is the centralizer of $ T $ in $ G $. So my guess for the first two questions is that $ N(T)/T  $ is always nontrivial and always disconnected.

Also curious about the group $ N(T)/T $ for more general subgroups $ T $ of $ G $.

Comment: I did not think much about it, but why don't you consider some examples first. Take $G = U(n)$ with say $n > 2$ for example, and $T$ the subgroup of $U(n)$ consisting of diagonal matrices having say ones everywhere except in the first $m$ entries (with $1 \leq m \leq n$). Working out this example will probably give clues.

Comment: In my previous example, $N(T)$ contains $(T \rtimes S_m) \times U(n-m)$ and I think they are equal (though I did not check carefully).

Comment: Your example makes it obvious that the centralizer of a small abelian subgroup is way bigger than just some maximal torus containing that abelian subgroup. Thanks @Malkoun! I've updated the last part of my question in response.

Comment: Note that $Z(T)$ is a normal subgroup of $N(T)$, and that the quotient is the corresponding Weyl group $W$ of $(G,T)$. If I remember semidirect products well, I think this implies that $N(T) \simeq Z(T) \rtimes W$. Also look at the short exact sequence $1 \to Z(T)/T \to N(T)/T \to W \to 1$. I think this implies that $N(T)/T \simeq Z(T)/T \rtimes W$. Please double check my statements.

Comment: In my example above, $Z(T) = T \times U(n-m)$ and $W = S_m$, so this agrees with my claim that $N(T) \simeq Z(T) \rtimes W$.

Comment: I just refreshed my memory on semidirect products, and actually, in order to say that $G \simeq N \rtimes H$, you need not just a short exact sequence of groups, such as $1 \to N \to G \to H \to 1$, but you also need a group homomorphism $i: H \to G$, which is a right-inverse of the projection map $G \to H$. So essentially, one needs to realize the Weyl group $W$ as an appropriate subgroup of $G$. In my example above, where $G = U(n)$, one may realize $W$ as a subgroup consisting of permutation matrices. It becomes a bit less obvious how to do that in general though...